# Yaml not being processed correctly when using array

Tags: json, typescript, parsing, yaml, idp

This yaml works fine for me

```
---
idp:
  type: oauth
  resources:
    - type: api
      name: my-name
      external_facing: false
      allowed_scopes:  #These are the scopes that are available to use.
        - read 
        - write
        - reports
        - admin
      allowed_clients:
        - artifact_guid: <senstive-info>   
          environment_keys:
            - development
          scopes: 
            - read
            - write
    - type: client
      name: oauthclient
```

Although I want to add in another idp config so wish to use this in an array, tried this

```
---
idp:
  - type: oauth
    resources:
      - type: api
        name: my-name
        external_facing: false
        allowed_scopes:
          - read
          - write
          - reports
          - admin
        allowed_clients:
          - artifact_guid: <sensitive-info>   
            environment_keys:
              - development 
            scopes:  
              - read
              - write
          - type: client
            name: oauthclient  
  - provider: azure
    applications:
      - name: my-name
        home_page_url: <sensitive info>
        email_address: <sensitive info>
        oidc: true
        reply_urls:
          - <sensitive info>
          - <sensitive info>
```

The error i get on the second yaml suggests the Artifact Guid is not being read correctly as deployment is complaining it cannot find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
    - type: client
      name: oauthclient
```

were indented incorrectly on the below format